# How to use Javascript to construct a mixture of json objects from a json request

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a json request input below and would want to construct a specific json format that the backend needs using javascript. What is the best way or steps to construct them? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Request input :

```
{
"Product": "abc"'
"Data": "{"Name":"John","Email":"john@example.com"}"
}
```

Request output to the backend as follow:

```
{
  "variables": {
    "Product": {
      "value": "abc",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Data": {
      "value": "{"Name":"John","Email":"john@example.com"}",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "Key": "123"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can just map over all the entries in your object.

Documentation: [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const input = {
  Product: "abc",
  Data: "{\"Name\":\"John\",\"Email\":\"john@example.com\"}"
};
const variables = Object.entries(input).reduce((output, [key, value]) => {
  output[key] = {
    type: typeof value,
    value
  };
  return output;
}, {});

const result = {
  variables,
  key: '123'
};
console.log(result);
```